# Word used to describe "exam essay"?

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for a word used to describe an "exam essay", so that when I say this word, others will know I'm referring to an essay/article written according to the rules of an examination. Is there a word has this meaning?

Also, I want to know is "exam essay" a common phrase to show this meaning?

Answer (score 1):

**Exam essay** has the exact meaning you are looking for and is a common expression

> I wrote an **exam essay** as practice for my class on *How To Take Tests And Win*

**Exam essays** are usually written while taking a **written exam** or an **essay exam**

Answer (score 0):

In my academic history (high school, college and postgrad work in the U.S.) I had many *"essay tests."*

I would have understood the term *exam essay* to be an essay written during an exam, but I have never used that term myself.  I would have referred to such a work product as "as essay I wrote for an exam."

The *essay test* would be an exam comprised solely of *essay questions* - those requiring a short essay for answers.

[N-Grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=exam%20essay%2Cessay%20test&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexam%20essay%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cessay%20test%3B%2Cc0)  registers both *"exam essay"* and *"essay test."*